# pip instal pandasでホイールを構築できないとなります

Tags: python, pandas, pip

python初心者です。

環境はWindows10、Python 3.8.0です。VScodeを使っています。

`pip install pandas` を実行すると以下のように表示されます。

```
Could not build wheels for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for six, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
```

pandasのインストールは問題なくできていますが、無視しても問題ないでしょうか。
後々、不具合が出てしまうでしょうか。

Comment: 単なるユーザーである間は不要な気がします。自分でパッケージを作成したり、それで使う他のパッケージをオフラインの実行環境にインストールするといった場合に必要になるのでは？ [【Python】pipとwheel](https://qiita.com/kenta1984/items/16a14f3bfaf1f257c585), [プロジェクトのパッケージング](https://python-packaging-user-guide-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/distributing.html#packaging-your-project), [PEP 427 -- The Wheel Binary Package Format 1.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) 気になるならサイズが小さいのでインストールしてしまっても良いのでは？ [wheel 0.34.2 - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/#files)

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678445/could-not-build-wheels-since-package-wheel-is-not-installed
に書いてあるようですが，

```
pip install wheel
```

で行けると思います。djangoで同じようになりましたが私も解消されましたよ！